# A formula for the generating function of Hoggatt binomials or of some Young tableaux

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, young-tableaux

Let  ${\left\langle\matrix {n \cr k}\right\rangle}_r$  denote the $r-$Hoggatt binomials defined by
$${{\left\langle\matrix {n \cr k}\right\rangle}_r=\frac{\langle n \rangle_r!}{\langle k \rangle_r! \langle n-k \rangle_r!}}$$
with ${\langle n\rangle}_r!= {\langle 1\rangle}_r\dots{\langle n\rangle}_r$, where ${\langle n\rangle}_r=\binom{n+r-1}{r}$ and let
$D$ be the differentiation operator.

The well-known formula $$\frac{1}{k!}D^k {\frac{1}{1-x}}=\sum_{n\geq0}\binom{n+k}{k}x^n$$  generalizes to a formula for the generating function of the $r-$Hoggatt binomials

$$\prod_{j=0}^{r-1}\frac{j!}{(k+j)!}(x^{r-1}D^r)^k \frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n\geq0}{\left\langle\matrix {n+k \cr k}\right\rangle}_r x^{n+r-1}.$$

An explicit expression of the $r-$Hoggatt binomials is
$${\left\langle\matrix {n \cr k}\right\rangle}_r=  \prod_{1 \le i \le k} \frac{(n - i + 1)^{\overline{r}}}{(k - i + 1)^{\overline{r}}}$$ where $x^{\overline{r}}$ denotes the rising factorial $x(x + 1) \dots (x + r-1).$

The right-hand side can be interpreted as the number of semistandard Young tableaux with shape $r^k.$

**Questions:** Does the above formula for the generating function of the $r-$Hoggatt binomials occur in the literature about Young tableaux? Has it a combinatorial interpretation or proof?

Comment: "number of semistandard Young tableaux with shape $r^k$"... and entries in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ I presume? If so, then these are also counting plane partitions in a box, and of course there are many formulas for plane partitions (where maybe your differentiation operator generating function appears).

Comment: There are two well-known formulas for counting SSYTs: https://www.symmetricfunctions.com/schur.htm#schurSpecializations
one is the hook-content, and the other is via the Weyl formula for Schur polynomials. However, I have not seen the term "r-Hoggatt" in any paper mentioning Schur polynynomials (but I do not claim to have read all such papers).

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that 2-Hoggatt binomials are the [Narayana numbers](http://oeis.org/A090181) and that the OEIS also has [3-Hoggatt binomials](http://oeis.org/A056939), [4-Hoggatt binomials](http://oeis.org/A056940), [5-Hoggatt binomials](http://oeis.org/A056941), and [6-Hoggatt binomials](http://oeis.org/A142465). I see that the OP is cited in some of these entries.

Comment: @Per Alexandersson: Perhaps I should have formulated my question in the following way: Is it pure chance that Hoggatt binomials count SSYTs or is there some relation between SSYTs and  powers of  differential operators x^(r-1)D^r ?

Answer (score 3):

This is too long for a comment, but I seem to have asked a [similar question here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/339765/iterated-derivative-and-rectangular-standard-young-tableaux).

The related paper is [this one](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379514001621), where some iterated derivative is computed, but no mention of SSYT. There should be a refinement of your question, which also takes the descents of a SSYT into consideration.

If you look at the answer on the MO-question I asked, then there is a proof by Greta Panova. I suspect that one can adapt that proof.